# Make MySql Workbench show line breaks

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Is it possible to make MySql Workbench not concatenate all lines of a LONGTEXT field in the Result Grid? I have a table where the data have multiple lines (which shows perfectly if I choose "Open Value in Editor") and would like the Result Grid to only show the first line, but now it adds the second line after the first one and the result looks like a mess.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say which version of MySQL Workbench you use, but recently a "form editor" mode was added that allows to switch to a view where you only see one record at a time, but have multiline edit controls for longer text fields.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I'm using the most recent version on Mac (6.1.7). Yes, there is that Form Editor, but for me my "LONGTEXT" field still is only one row (but at least it doesn't concatenate with next row). How did you make it show more rows? Preferably tho I'd like to see the first row of all results in the grid.

Comment: Try 6.2, I think this has been fixed there.

Comment: Have the same issue on OSX using MySQLWorkbench 6.3.9 on a `mediumtext` column.